# IE загружает iframe как гость

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

Ранее с таким не сталкивался.
Гугл и Яндекс не спасли.

Есть страница на сайте, для авторизованного пользователя она выводит одни данные, для гостя - другие.
Есть другая страница (другой домен), которая выводит содержимое первой через iframe.

Во всех браузерах фрэйм грузится от авторизованного пользователя (если он авторизован), IE же грузит от гостя (т.е. во фрэйме отображается страница как будто её просматривает гость, хотя на сайте я авторизован).

Почему так и можно ли это решить?
Вроде как запросы с домена на домен и так и так нельзя отправить, IE ещё и фрэймы блокирует? На всякий случай?

Comment: Если у кого-то возникнет подобная проблема, то мсье **Vlad911** подсказывает готовое решение вот здесь - https://toster.ru/q/3471

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE не отсылает куки внешней страницы во фрейм, если внешняя страница не возвращает заголовок HTTP-заголовок с именем P3P примерно такого вида:

```
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR".
```

P3P - это [Platform for Privacy Preferences](http://www.w3.org/P3P/). Значение примерно переводится как [Compact Policy](http://www.w3.org/TR/P3P11/#compact_policies) = collects [contact and others](http://www.w3.org/TR/P3P11/#ACCESS), for [pseudo-analysis](http://www.w3.org/TR/P3P11/#PURPOSE), data collected for [ours](http://www.w3.org/TR/P3P11/#RECPNT):

Без него IE фрейму не верит и аутентификационные и сессионные куки, ему не передает.

Если вы разработчик и у вас не передаются куки во фрейм - добавьте хедер.

Если вы пользователь сайта, и этого заголовка нет - пишите разработчиками.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь знаю как обойти, буду пробовать. Попробовал сделать вот что: в самом IE установить настройку "принимать cookie" с этого сайта - не сработало. Пойду переводить туториалы по P3P :)

Comment: Порылся глубже по теме - нашёл, по сути, готовое решение - всё заработало. Спасибо:)